# Which box is heavier

Tags: geometry, puzzle

There are 2 identical boxes (cubes). First one contains 27 big identical marbles and second one contains 64 small identical marbles. The marbles are made by steel. Supposing that in each box the marbles are next to each other, which box is heavier?

Comment: When you say "the marbles are next to each other" do you mean they fit into the boxes with no room to move, or perhaps they fit into the base of the box with no room to move?

Comment: The second box will be heavier, since the smaller marbles will have a higher packing density. As a way to visualize this, imagine the smaller marbles becoming much smaller, until they are the size of sand. You will be able to fit much more matter into the box. The same is true to a lesser extent for slightly smaller marbles

Comment: I think it refers to the fact that there is no space between 2 consecutive marbles, I do not know exactly. There is no further information about what this could mean.

Comment: @penguina I'm assuming the question is saying that they are as close together as they can be. Imagine shaking each box until they lie still, so there are no large pockets of empty space. Check out [sphere packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) : it is impossible for there to be no space between the marbles.

Comment: @J.Bush sure, I meant to say that the marbles touches each other (there are not 2 marbles that do not touch)

Comment: Do you know if the marbles are to be arranged such that the 27 big marbles are such that they form 3 rows of 3 by 3 marbles and the 64 small marbles are such that they form 4 rows of 4 by 4 marbles?

Comment: @jim No, you do not know anything about the way they are arranged.

Comment: @J.Bush: That does not follow.  For instance, hexagonal close-packed has the same proportion of empty space no matter how small the circles are.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now, I have not seen that mistake with volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both marbles are made of the same material with the same density $\rho$, and also assuming that the same amount of volume is occupied in total by the ($27$ or $64$)marbles in each box.

Let $r$, $R$ be the radius of the smaller and bigger marbles respectively.

Let the cubic box have side $s$ with volume $V = s^3$.

$$\therefore V = 64 \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = 27 \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$$
$$\therefore 64r^3 = 27R^3$$
$$\therefore 4r = 3R$$
$$\therefore \frac{r}{R} = \frac{3}{4}$$
The weight of the box due to the marbles in each case shall be,
$$W_1 = 27 W_R , W_2 = 64 W_r$$
$$\therefore \frac{W_1}{W_2} = \frac{27W_R}{64W_r}$$
Since both marble types have the same density, therefore
$$\rho_r = \rho_R$$
$$W_r/V_r = W_R/V_R$$
$$W_r/(\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3) = W_R/(\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3)$$
$$\frac{W_r}{W_R} = (\frac{r}{R})^3$$
$$\therefore \frac{W_r}{W_R} = \frac{27}{64}$$
$$\therefore \frac{W_1}{W_2} = 1$$
$$\therefore W_2 = W_1$$

Hence both cubical boxes will weight the same.

Comment: If two batches of marbles all have the same density and both occupy the same volume, then the two batches must have *identical* weights!  There is an obvious error in concluding $W_r/W_R=1$:  How can a big marble weigh the same as a small one?

Comment: No.  In your last run of analysis, from the second line to the third, you changed $V_r$ from the volume of an individual marble to the volume of all the marbles in that box. ¶ Think about it: How could the small marbles and the large marbles *individually* have the same weight, if they have the same density?  Your initial assumptions have them having the same density and the same total volume; they must therefore have the same *total* weight!

Comment: @BrianTung : Right, sorry about that, fixed it now.

Comment: @rotaiva: You've fixed the analysis in the last part, but your second part is wrong.  There aren't more of the larger marbles, there must be fewer of them: $W_1 = 64W_r, W_2 = 27W_R$, not the other way around. ¶ You sort of ignored the conceptual flaw pointed out by both myself and Barry Cipra.

Comment: @BrianTung :Yes, I just realized that, I fixed that as well, my answer now reads that both boxes will weigh the same. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rotaiva: OK, good! :-)

Comment: It doesn't really affect the conclusion, but there is still a problem with the opening equation $V=64{4\over3}\pi r^3=27{4\over3}\pi R^3$, which seems to be asserting the marbles in each box occupy the *entire* volume $V=s^3$ of the box!

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer.** If we assume that the marbles are packed in a cubical lattice (as is suggested by the numbers $27 = 3^3$ and $64 = 4^3$), then the smaller marbles have $27/64$ times the volume of the larger ones, but that is exactly compensated for by the fact that there are $64/27$ times as many of them.  The marbles in each box thus have the same total weight.

However, if we cannot assume that, and in fact the marbles are as large as possible while still fitting into the box, the problem becomes much more complex.  I suspect that the sphere-packing-into-cube problem is not solved for $27$ or $64$ spheres.  One would tend to suspect that $64$ spheres could pack into a cube more efficiently than $27$ could (and therefore the $64$-sphere cube would weigh more), but I can't be sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

From 27 to 64, I think the answer is that they are the same.  If the number of marbles is small, the most efficient packing is in a square (or cubical) latices.  But, when the number of marbles is sufficiently large, dodecahedral structure is more effient (the same pattern your grocer uses to stack oranges).

The dodecahedral structure is less efficient around the walls of the box, and more efficient in the interior of the box.  This is why the number of marbles has to pass some minimal condition before they would settle into the more efficient packing.  As the number of marbles increases, the theoretical efficiency increases as there are proportionally fewer marbles against the walls of the box.

As the numbers get large you approach some limit of packing efficiency.  As I remember 72%